# What would be the appropriate FHIR Resource and element for an "Intake Date"

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am implementing a FHIR API, and I need to find the right place to communicate the date that a patient started an intake process. This intake process is to determine the patient's eligibility for a particular healthcare program.

Is there an appropriate place for this in FHIR v4.0.0? Or, do I need to shoehorn this in as a Basic resource?

Comment: what's an 'intake process'. is this registration for a clinical process?

Comment: @GrahameGrieve It's more like registration for a financial & clinical process. It's a process for checking a Patient's eligibility for a particular Medicare program.

Practice staff check paperwork, financials, etc. and then they give the Yes/No that the Patient can "enroll" in the program.

Comment: @ELYusubov Not really. It's the date that practice staff start checking eligibility for coverage (in a sense).

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with CoverageRequest, and put the date in the `created` field. This made the most semantic sense - as the date the patient is requesting "coverage" under this particular healthcare program.

I'm basically generalizing the concept of "coverage" to include programs as well as insurance plans.

Comment: did you mean the resource named as [CoverageEligibilityReques ](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/coverageeligibilityrequest.html) ?